# Nand2tetris Mult.hack doesn't exist

Tags: nand2tetris

I have compeleted the Mult.asm,and I have tested manually to be sure it is correct, but every time I try to test it with Mult.tst, an error message comes up.Here is my code and my error messages.

// Multply R2=R1*R0

```
@R2
M=0 
@R1
D=M
@n
M=D
```

(LOOP)

```
@R0
D=M
@R2
M=D+M
@n
M=M-1
D=M
@LOOP
D;JGT
```

(END)
@END
0;JMP

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Acx.jpg)

I want to know what is wrong with this and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, while you can load .asm files into the CPU emulator and they automatically get compiled, the test scripts require a .hack file (ie: the output of the assembler).

Use the Assembler to compile your .asm file and generate the needed .hack file.